# How can I get my Java proxy to serve up a video on the iPad?

Tags: java, ios, ipad, video, proxy

We have some videos (mp4) that are stored behind our firewall.  I have a Java proxy that is used to serve up other documents like PDFs, DOCs, etc. to external sites via a RESTful web service.  This same web service works for videos in PC browsers but on the iPad I just get a black screen with the play button blocked.  If I browse to the direct location of the video it plays fine.  That leads me to believe the video is fine, but I am missing something in my web service code that serves it back up.  Any ideas out there?  Has anyone else conquered this on the iPad?

```
    @GET
    @Path("/open/{objectId}/{ticket}/{objectName}/")
    public Response openDocument(@PathParam("objectId") String objectId, @PathParam("ticket") String ticket, @PathParam("objectName") String objectName) throws Exception {
        return download(objectId, ticket, objectName, false);
    }

    private Response download(String objectId, String ticket, String objectName, boolean attachment) throws Exception {

        String url = "";
        if (objectName.endsWith(".mp4")) {
            url = "http://videosite.com/videos/" + objectName;
        }
        else {
            url = "http://documentsite.com/" + objectName;
        }

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);

        try {

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
            if (status.getStatusCode() == 200 || status.getStatusCode() == 206) {

                ResponseBuilder rb = Response.ok(entity.getContent());

                rb.header("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                rb.header("Content-Length", entity.getContentLength());
                rb.header("Content-Type", entity.getContentType().getValue());
                rb.header("Keep-Alive", "timeout=5, max=99");

                if (attachment) rb.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + objectName.replaceAll("\\+", " ") + "\"");
                else rb.header("Content-Disposition", "filename=\"" + objectName.replaceAll("\\+", " ") + "\"");

                return rb.build();
            }
            else return Response.noContent().build();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Response.noContent().build();
        } 
    }
```